# How to calculate the Total amount depending upon the subtotal and shipping charges in php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making the shopping cart. I am able to calculate the product price depending upon the quantity.

Now I am calculating the total amount depending upon the subtotal and shipping charges with the product price.

When I am increasing the quantity of product it's calculating the product price but not calculating the subtotal and total amount.

Or Is there any other secure way to handle this?

Would you help me out in this?

```js
$('a.ddd').click(function() {

    var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
    var $pro_list = $(this).closest('tr.pro-list');
    var productPrice = parseFloat($pro_list.find('span.price_cal').text());
    var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
    var newQuantity = parseFloat($quantityInput.val()) + parseFloat($(this).data('multi'));

    if (newQuantity>= 1) {

        // Refresh quantity input.
        $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

        // Refresh total div.
        var lineTotal = productPrice*newQuantity;
        $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').data('price','&#163;'+lineTotal).html('&#163;'+lineTotal);
    }

});
```

```css
.sp-quantity {
    width:124px;
    height:42px;
    float: left;
}
.sp-minus {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.sp-input {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left:0px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.sp-plus {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left:0px solid #e1e1e1;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.sp-input input {
    width:30px;
    height:34px;
    text-align:center;
    border: none;
}
.sp-input input:focus {
    border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border: none;
}
.sp-minus a, .sp-plus a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table class="table cart-table">
                    <thead class="table-headings">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="pname">Product</th>
                            <th class="punit">Unit Price</th>
                            <th class="pquant">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="ptotal">Total price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['products'])):
             foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product):?>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td>
                                <div class="ordered-product cf">
                                    <div class="pro-img">
                                        <img src="admin/images/products/<?php echo $product['p_images'];?>" alt=" prodcut image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pro-detail-name">
                                        <h3><?php echo $product['p_name'];?></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                    $p_delete=$product['p_id'];
                                    //$decrypted_delete_id = decryptIt($p_delete);
  
                                    $encrypted_user_id = encryptIt($p_delete);
                                    $delete_product_id=urlencode($encrypted_user_id);
                                    ?>

                                    <a href="my-cart?action=empty&deletekey=<?php echo $delete_product_id;?>" class="cross-cta"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>&#163;<span class="price_cal"><?php echo $product['p_currentprice'];?></span></td>
                            <td>

                                <div class="sp-quantity">
                                    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
                                    <div class="sp-input">
                                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="<?php echo $product['qty'];?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                                <?php $single_total = $product['qty']*$product['p_currentprice'];?>
                                <td class='total_amount' data-price='&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?>'>&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?></td>

                        </tr>
                            <?php $total = $total+$single_total;
                            $_SESSION['total_cost']=$total;
                            endforeach;?>
                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>Subtotal</span></td>
                            <td class='total_amount' data-price='&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?>'>&#163;<?php echo $single_total;?></td>
<!--                             <td><span>Shiping Cost</span></td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i>&#163;<?php echo $total;?></td> -->
                        </tr>


                        <tr class="pro-list">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><span>Total Cost</span></td>
                            <td>&#163;<?php echo $total;?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </table>
```

Comment: You didn't write any code for calculating sub-total and total. What are the formulas for sub-total and total?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM, I updated my code with PHP. Please check it.

Comment: You are mistaking PHP with jQuery, which is a JavaScript library. Probably caused by the use of `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition to your code below should do it!

Added some class names to make it easier to find values. Added with a jQuery each the product prices up to a subtotal and displayed in the subtotal line. Then add 20 shipping cost to the total. The jQuery is pretty self explanatory.

```js
updateTotal();
$('a.ddd').click(function() {

  var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
  var $pro_list = $(this).closest('tr.pro-list');
  var productPrice = parseFloat($pro_list.find('span.price_cal').text());
  var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
  var newQuantity = parseFloat($quantityInput.val()) + parseFloat($(this).data('multi'));

  if (newQuantity >= 1) {

    // Refresh quantity input.
    $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

    // Refresh total div.
    var lineTotal = productPrice * newQuantity;
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').html('&#163;' + lineTotal);
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').data('price', lineTotal); //update data-price
  }
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
  var subTotal = 0;
  var currencySymbol = "£";

  //start getting the total amounts from each product row.
  //add them as a subtotal.
  $("tr.pro-list > td.total_amount").each(function(index, element) {
    subTotal += parseFloat($(element).data("price")); //more secure to use data!
  });

  var total = subTotal + $("tr.pro-list.ship > td[data-price]").data("price");
  $("tr.pro-list.sub > td.subtotal").html(currencySymbol + "" + subTotal);
  $("tr.pro-list.total > td.total").html(currencySymbol + "" + total);
}
```

```css
.sp-quantity {
  width: 124px;
  height: 42px;
  float: left;
}

.sp-minus {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sp-input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-left: 0px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.sp-plus {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-left: 0px solid #e1e1e1;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.sp-input input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}

.sp-input input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  border: none;
}

.sp-minus a,
.sp-plus a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pro-list">
      <td>
        <div class="ordered-product cf">
          <div class="pro-detail-name">
            <h3>ProductName</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>&#163;<span class="price_cal">55</span></td>
      <td>
        <div class="sp-quantity">
          <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
          <div class="sp-input">
            <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="2" />
          </div>
          <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class='total_amount' data-price='110'>&#163;110</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pro-list">
      <td>
        <div class="ordered-product cf">
          <div class="pro-detail-name">
            <h3>ProductName</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>&#163;<span class="price_cal">45</span></td>
      <td>
        <div class="sp-quantity">
          <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
          <div class="sp-input">
            <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="2" />
          </div>
          <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="ddd" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class='total_amount' data-price='90'>&#163;90</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="pro-list sub">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span>Subtotal</span></td>
      <td class="subtotal">&#163;110</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pro-list ship">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span>Shipping charges</span></td>
      <td data-price="20">&#163;20</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pro-list total">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span>Total Amount</span></td>
      <td class="total">&#163;110</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please give me some time to understand the flow of it

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more robust.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am facing this issue more than 11 days and you solved it within 5 min. Really appreciate. Upvote from my side.

Comment: I just want to know the this is the right thing I am doing it for a shopping cart?

Comment: Well if I've helped you, please mark this as the correct answer, upvote would be nice. To answer your last question. The client stuff is important, because it should give the user/customer security that what he is seeing will eventually be the amount he's paying. The real handling happens on the server. If you want to calculate the amounts, my advice is always start with zero and with every update recalculate the whole amount. That way you're sure the math always is correct. Also recalculate before posting to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the information.Now my next module is checkout. So I just want to know with the help of session can I do? I mean I will set the price in the session and display in the checkout page. Is it the right way to do checkout process?

Comment: Preferably you want to store session data about a customer being logged in - the actual data about the sale I would put in a database. That way you can also track sale statistics and store inventory. That way you can always retrieve the information at a later moment.

Comment: Ok. But when I can store that information in the database? After clicking on Process to check out?

Comment: I would do that when the user proceeds to check out indeed. Try to store his data in localstorage or session storage as a back up.

Comment: ok.You mean to say.After click on proceed to check out at that time, I have to store the data in database